# React Component - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, use-state

I am building a little local dev/testing/documentation environment for some components which are used across different projects and so want to create them as individual npm packages.

Everything was working perfectly until I tried to use `useState()` in one of the components. Add this created the following errors:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
```

I feel this is strange and I can't figure out what is causing it. I also tested with other hooks to see if it was just `useState` that was the problem but others such as `useEffect` and `useRef` also have the same problem.

Project structure is:

```
/components (the components to develop/test/document
    /component-group
        /Component
            index.js
            Component.js
            component.scss
            package.json
/library  (where all the components are developed/tested/documented)
    /component1
    /component2
    /etc (all the components that make up the library)
webpack.config.js
package.json
etc...
```

Components are imported into the library using a relative path because I don't won't to have to publish them to npm and update the version locally every time a change is made and needs to be tested.

As for the code for the component where `useState` is causing problems, this is a basic version which still causes problems:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {

    const [testState, setTestState] = useState("testing");

    return (
        <p>Hello World</p>
    )

}

export default TestComponent
```

If I comment out the `useState` line then Hello World is displayed, if I uncomment the line then the errors appear.

Any ideas as to what might be wrong would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show pls how you use component and where

Comment: I think there might be some problems with node modules of your project.
Please make sure to reinstall node modules by npm install (yarn install).

Comment: @iceFox I have just tried this and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Managed to fix this using the Webpack alias property as explained in this tutorial: https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/duplicate-dependencies-npm-link/